# Unable to return value of dropdown value in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, submit, dropdown

I am trying to retrieve a dropdown value, but the value isn't being returned in PHP. It returns as empty. I have other dropdowns in the form, but the only difference between them and this one is that there is a function associated to it. Which the javascript actually returns.

Thanks for your help. Code for the dropdown is below.

```js
function validateDays() {
  var e = document.getElementById("age_category");
  var age_category = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  if (age_category == "Sub-Junior") {
    console.log("Success");
  } else {
    console.log("Not Sub-Junior");
  }
}
```

```html
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo $age_category = $_POST['age_category']
  }
?>
  <form action="my_page.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <!-- AGE CATEGORY -->
      <select class="form-control" name="age_category" id="age_category" onchange="validateDays();" required>
       <option value="">Age Category</option>
        <option value="Sub-Junior">Sub-Junior</option>
        <option value="Junior">Junior</option>
        <option value="Open">Open</option>
        <option value="Master 1">Master 1</option>
        <option value="Master 2">Master 2</option>
        <option value="Master 3">Master 3</option>
        <option value="Master 4">Master 4</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: check your console and use php's error reporting, should there be errors

Comment: That code is working for me when I put it into a new PHP file. Try isolating it, so if this part is working, maybe something isn't calling it properly, which I can't tell with the code you provided.

Comment: Show your php code where you are trying to use the value from the form

Comment: This code can be shortened also:   `<option value="Junior" <?php if (isset($age_category) && $age_category=="Junior") echo "selected";?>>Junior</option>`
 make it 
`<option value="Junior" <?php echo
 isset($age_category) && $age_category =="Junior" ? "selected" : "" ?></option>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. When I was checking to see if it was empty. I was actually assigning it to be empty.

So it looked like this

```
if($age_category = "")
```

instead of

```
if($age_category == "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You trying get **submit** value:
$_POST['submit']
and You need **age_category**:
$_POST['age_category']

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check isset function on $_POST['submit'] but "submit" reference doesn't exists anywhere in your form.

First create a button or something else and name it "submit" and then submit your form.

Currently you are not submitting your form in your code